# Python - how to print amount of numbers, periods, and commas in file

Tags: python

```
def showCounts(fileName):
lineCount = 0
wordCount = 0
numCount = 0
comCount = 0
dotCount = 0

with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        lineCount += 1
        wordCount += len(words)

        for word in words:
#                ###text = word.translate(string.punctuation)
            exclude = set(string.punctuation)
            text = ""
            text = ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude)
            try:
                if int(text) >= 0 or int(text) < 0:
                    numCount += 1
                # elif text == ",":
                    # comCount += 1
                # elif text == ".":
                    # dotCount += 1
            except ValueError:
                pass

print("Line count: " + str(lineCount))
print("Word count: " + str(wordCount))
print("Number count: " + str(numCount))
print("Comma count: " + str(comCount))
print("Dot  count: " + str(dotCount) + "\n")
```

---

Basically it will show the number of lines and the number of words, but I can't get it to show the number of numbers, commas, and dots. I have it read a file that the user enters and then show the amount of lines and words, but for some reason it says 0 for numbers commas and dots. I commented out the part where it gave me trouble. If i remove the comma then i just get an error. thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code loops over every character in each line, and adds 1 to its variable:

```
numCount = 0
dotCount = 0
commaCount = 0
lineCount = 0
wordCount = 0

fileName = 'test.txt'

with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        wordCount+=len(line.split())
        lineCount+=1
        for char in line:
            if char.isdigit() == True:
                numCount+=1
            elif char == '.':
                dotCount+=1
            elif char == ',':
                commaCount+=1

print("Number count: " + str(numCount))
print("Comma count: " + str(commaCount))
print("Dot  count: " + str(dotCount))
print("Line count: " + str(lineCount))
print("Word count: " + str(wordCount))
```

**Testing it out:**

`test.txt`:

```
Hello, my name is B.o.b. I like biking, swimming, and running.

I am 125 years old, and  I was 124 years old 1 year ago.

Regards,
B.o.b
```

**Running:**

```
bash-3.2$ python count.py
Number count: 7
Comma count: 5
Dot  count: 7
Line count: 6
Word count: 27
bash-3.2$
```

Everything makes sense here, except the `lineCount` the reason why this is `6` is because of newlines. In my editor (*nano*), it adds a newline to the end of any file by default. So just imagine the text file to be this:

```
>>> x = open('test.txt').read()
>>> x
'Hello, my name is B.o.b. I like biking, swimming, and running.\n\nI am 125 years old, and  I was 124 years old 1 year ago.\n\nRegards,\nB.o.b \n'
>>> x.count('\n')
6
>>>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm. Odd. It got the numbers dots and commas right, but the numbers it provided for the lines and words were way higher than what they actually are...

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. The numbers commas and dots are good - thanks so much! for some reason i have 9 lines yet it says i have 98 and i have probably 20 words yet it says i have 304...

Comment: it helped but just provided me with even more questions - i am not sure as to why it gave a wrong number of lines and words?

Comment: Let me add a word count and line count

Answer (score 0):

For the punctuations, why not just do:

```
def showCounts(fileName):
    ...
    ...
    with open(fileName, 'r') as fl:
        f = fl.read()

    comCount = f.count(',')
    dotCount = f.count('.')
```

Comment: and then just keep the rest as it is now?

Comment: @TommyConnor, I believe so. Why don't you give it a try and see how it goes and then let me know.

Comment: I get this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assn.py", line 113, in <module>
    showCounts(THE_FILE)
  File "assn.py", line 61, in showCounts
    words = line.split()
NameError: global name 'line' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Counter` class to take care of it you:

```
from collections import Counter

with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    data    = f.read().strip()
    lines   = len(data.split('\n'))
    words   = len(data.split())
    counts  = Counter(data)
    numbers = sum(v for (k,v) in counts.items() if k.isdigit())

print("Line count: {}".format(lines))
print("Word count: {}".format(words))
print("Number count: {}".format(numbers))
print("Comma count: {}".format(counts[',']))
print("Dot count: {}".format(counts['.']))
```

Comment: this says lines is not defined?

Comment: @TommyConnor It works for me. Are you sure you're assigning to `lines` and not `line` inside the context manager?